# How to filter elements from downstream transforms in the pipeline, without sending a"NoneType"?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I need to remove elements in the pipeline that correspond to old data. i.e:data before Jan 1st 2019. When I implement this, the downstream transform is getting a "NoneType" error because the filtering sends a None, as opposed to just moving on to the next element. I need to be able to filter out data elements and just move on without returning anything.

This is for an Apache Beam pipeline, processing a streaming dataset from PubSub. I've attempted to just "pass", as well as handle for errors, and pass a side collection that can add the if/else/pass logic.

```
def timedelay(element):...

def data_trim_enhance(element):
    # Will filter out old sensor data 
    old_data_limit = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    date_to_compare = datetime.strptime(element.attributes['_last_updt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

    if date_to_compare < old_data_limit:
        # print(date_to_compare)
        pass
    else:
        return "some data"

def run():

    chi_traffic = (pipeline
                   | 'ReadPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_name, with_attributes=True)
                   # [START window_and_trigger] - Set a fixed window at 10 minutes based on evnt_timestamp attribute
                   | 'TrafficFixedWindows' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10),
                                                              trigger=trigger.AfterWatermark(trigger.AfterCount(10)),
                                                              accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
                   # [END window_and_trigger] - Wait for AfterCount(x) pub/sub messages
                   | 'GeoEnrich&Trim' >> beam.Map(data_trim_enhance)
                   | 'TimeDelayEnrich' >> beam.Map(timedelay)
                   | 'TrafficRatingEnrich' >> beam.Map(traffic_rating)
                   | 'MergeAccidents' >> beam.Map(merge_accidents, pcoll=pvalue.AsDict(accident_data))
                   | 'WritetoBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                        table='{0}:{1}.{2}'.format(project_id, dataset_id, table_name),
                                                        schema=table_schema
                                                            ))
```

Once the window triggers, I expect that the next transform down(timedelay) to get the data processed from data_trim_enhance. However, I end up getting a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute *". I've tried handling this through the various functions, but it ends up just getting kicked down the road till it hits the "WritetoBQ" and errors out on the NoneType. I need to just skip the element that is old, and send nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I've figured out the issue. The heart of the problem is essentially based on a Map vs FlatMap comparison.

- Map takes a single input and MUST put out a single output.
- FlatMap, however, has the ability to take in a single output, but return **0, or more elements**. This means that it won't tag an entry with a NoneType in a return. Hence the main issue was resolved.

In my code, I utilized a Map transform for data_trim_enhance, when it should have been a FlatMap since I'm using that function to trim/filter data from the origin, and completely shed it.

I had tried the FlatMap before, but it was distorting my dictionary. To solve that, I simply enclosed the dictionary with list notation.

Hope this helps someone!